# Effect of myelination on inteligence in cephalopods

Tags: genetics, invertebrates, intelligence, neuron, artificial-life

Cephalopods are known for their unique intelligence compared to other invertebrates. 
The number of neurons of cephalopods is of the order $5*10^8$, similar to dogs. Humans have about $10^{11}$ neurons.

However, a major difference between cephalopods and humans and most vertebrates is the lack of myelination of their axons. Instead, to quickly transmit signals, cephalopod axons are much larger, reaching sizes of up to 1mm.

If we could edit the genome of an octopus, so that its axons are coated in myelin similar to a humans axon, whilst retaining their size, would this change the intelligence or behaviour of the octopus because of the increased processing speed?

Edit:
This is a repost of my original questions, to better conform with the guidelines of this forum. I am new to both this site and biology. Thank you very much for reading.